# Removing lines from Windows path variable

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

Let's say this is what my Windows system PATH looks like:

> C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\32bit\client_1\bin;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\64bit\client_1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

How would I remove that very first entry and add it to the end of the list?  I know you can use setx for this but I would rather do this using PowerShell.

Comment: Do you know the name of the variable that holds the PATH string in PowerShell? Why not do a loop to get each char of the string and copy it to $buffer1 until it gets to the first `";"`. After that, stop copying the chars to $buffer1 and start copying them to $buffer2 (that is, $buffer2 += $char). After the loop is done, simply set PATH to $buffer2 + $buffer1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# Split the existing path into the 1st entry and the rest.
$first, $rest = $env:Path -split ';'

# Rebuild the path with the first entry appended.
$env:Path = ($rest + $first) -join ';'

# To make this change persistent for the current user, 
# an extra step is needed:
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $env:Path, 'User')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!  I had seen some examples of other things using the -split command but wasn't really sure if it would be the best solution here or how to apply it.

Comment: @Chris; My pleasure; `-split`, `-join`, and `-replace` are powerful beasts - well worth getting to know them in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and simple way:

```
$values = 'C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\32bit\client_1\bin;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\64bit\client_1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WIN DOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\' -split ';'                                    #'

$result = $values[$values.Count-1] + ';'   
for($i = 1; $i -lt $values.Count-1; $i++){ $result += $values[$i] + ';' }
$result += $values[0]

$result
```

Comment: Thanks. The highlighter cannot deal with `\'`, which it interprets as an _escaped_ `'`, unfortunately. The workaround is to provide the "missing" closing `'` in an (off-screen) comment, which I've just done for your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but on my mobile phone there is #' visable. It seems like a failure in the post representation on mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - it's an imperfect workaround; you can make the comment visible on the desktop site as well, using horizontal scrolling, but at least it doesn't do any harm (the code still works).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with PowerShell scripting but I believe you can write plain C# in it.  If that's so then perhaps the C# helps.

Note that there are three PATH environment variables to choose from: the one given to the process, the one given to the user and the one given to the machine itself.  For the demo code below, I chose the one for the process.

```
var whichPath = EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process;

string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", whichPath);

string [] pathEntries = path.Split(';');

if (pathEntries.Length > 1)
{
    // Initialize to the necessary length, for efficiency.
    var sb = new StringBuilder(capacity: path.Length);
    for(int i = 1; i < pathEntries.Length; ++i)
    {
        sb.Append(pathEntries[i]).Append(';');
    }
    sb.Append(pathEntries[0]).Append(';');

    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", sb.ToString(), target: whichPath);
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are ways to compile C# code on demand in PowerShell (see [Add-Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type)), but the primary reason to do is performance (for _repeated_ tasks, because you do pay a performance penalty for the initial compilation).
The case at hand definitely does _not_ call for C# use, given that PowerShell can do the job much more concisely, because it (generally) operates at a higher level of abstraction.